# Flow Copying Values To different fields

Tags: visual-workflow, formula

I have the following challenge where I am wondering what the best practice would be:
We have one field calls Status__c on the Contact object. It has the following values inside:

Fieldname Status__c

type: Picklist

Values:

- Active
- Active Direct Marketing
- Passive
- Passiv Blacklist

We would like to exchange this field with the following ones

Fieldname: Active Contact

Type: Checkbox

Fieldname: Deactivation Reason

type: Picklist

Fieldname: Direct Marketing

Type: Checkbox

As the old Status__c is relavant for a lot of automation and reports etc we would like to keep it in the background and fill it with the fields from the new ones automatically. So the following mapping should be happening:

Active Contact = TRUE -> Status__c = Active

Active Contact = TRUE AND Direct Marketing = TRUE -> Status__c = Active Direct Marketing

Active Contact = FALSE -> Status__c = Passive

Active Contact = FALSE AND Deactivation Reason = Blacklist -> Status__c = Passive Blacklist

I was thinking to build a decision tree in the flow and I am not sure if this would be the best way to go? I hope someone can help me to find a sleek solution for this and not overload the elements. Many thanks in advance!

Comment: if you don't want to use a Decision Element, just use an Assignment element with the derived value computed by a formula

Comment: @cropredy If I would use a decision element I would need to use for each case one decision element, right? That would blow up the flow. Would kind of formula would you suggest if I may ask?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a couple of options

### Option 1 - A Decision element with 4 + default branches

**Branch 1** - Active Contact = TRUE & Direct Marketing = False => assignment element that sets Status to `Active`

**Branch 2** - Active Contact = TRUE & Direct Marketing = False => assignment element that sets Status to `Active Direct Marketiing`

**Branch 3** - Active Contact = FALSE & Deactivation Reason not equal Blacklist => assignment element that sets Status to `Passive`

**Branch 4** - Active Contact = FALSE & Deactivation Reason  equal Blacklist => assignment element that sets Status to `Passive Blacklist`

**Default branch** - do nothing

### Option 2 - A single Assignment Element using a Formula

Formula is a set of nested IFs that mirrors the 4 condition

e.g. `$Record.Status__c` = formula

```
IF (<condition1>,<statusValue,
IF (<condition2, <statusValue>,
IF (<condition3, <statusValue>,
IF (<condition4, <statusValue>,
NULL))))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I went in the end for the decision elements to clearly show whats going on. Many thanks once again and have a great mid of the week!

Comment: as a service to the community who might happen upon this question in the future, marking answers as accepted helps folks out

Comment: I am happy to do so. Just cannot find how. If you can give me small hint how I can do this?

Comment: click the ✓ to the left of the answer